# Recurrent neural networks and continual variables

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I am having an issue with processing continuous data using RNN. So far I've used MEL spectograms as inputs for my Listen, Attend and Spell architecture but I've decided to play around with that input by interpolating spectogram bins data rather than using MEL. Here is an example how one could achieve this: https://dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-interpolate-fft-peak/

The idea is simple, information gets lost in the process of creating MEL spectograms, some components get shifted etc. and my goal was to try and see if some sort of preprocessing could help deep network in the process of learning but I can't express this newly formed input to match RNN. MEL spectogram is 2D data with final number of bins, let's say 39. This new input can have arbitrary number of components for each time step. Every of these components is represented by a tuple of frequency and amplitude while both of them are continual variables. Frequency range for each time step can vary so I can't adopt a final number of them, first index for one time step could hold frequency value of, let's say, 5Hz while in the next time step it could very well be few hundreds of Hz. Could convolutional network be used as a tool before RNN? Is there any other solution? Thanks!